# Angular token and user login scenario

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, oauth-2.0, token

I m building app who uses oauth2.
I me using:

1. Laravel for backend
2. Oauth2 for Laravel (lucadegasperi)
3. Angular for frontend because it will be also and native mobile app:D.

My question is?
What is the workflow for user sign in?

Now i have.

1. User comes to site and enter username and password
   Angular send post for access token and when access token is returned i go for user data. Then I store access_token in localstorage. I m using grant_type=password i forget to mention.
2. I have 2 hours when token gona expire. In that moment when token expire I go for new token by refresh_token functionality.

My Questions are:

1. Is this good way/approach?
2. What is supposed to happen when user close browser? 
   Now when user close browser and again enter to my app. I will check localstorage and then autheticate user by access_token. If Access Token is expired i will get new one.
3. What about remeber me option or so called keep me signed in?
   Does it mean thant i must set token that will be expired in 365 days (lifetime)?
   or create cookie/ localstorage with access token so when user comes newt time i read cookie/loaclastorage and then authorize user?
4. And finnaly about destroying token. Now my token will be detroyed when i log of from the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are building the same kind of service/app using the same components. We use a password flow and I store the token in local storage if the user ticks the "remember me" checkbox on the login form, otherwise I just store the token in an un-persisted variable that gets destroyed when the user refreshes or closes the browser.

See some notes on testing protected endpoints here:[Testing OAuth 2.0 protected API endpoints in Laravel](http://www.onesheep.org/blog/2014/10/testing-oauth-2-0-protected-api-endpoints-in-laravel/)

Answer (score 0):

Marijan!

I'm working on simple app containing two separate layers. 1) Rails 5 Json API provider. 2) Separate NodeJS server running Angular 2 application.

1. Angular 2 app on Login requests access token from google
2. Angular 2 app retrieves UserInfo from google/people API
3. Angular 2 app now able to POST json with User's display name and some id from Google Response json.
4. Angular 2 POSTs json to my Rails 5 API server (partially implemented, but already works with login/pass auth).

So far I have implemented implicit OAuth2 using the code similar to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/homoluden/06ba0ba9f06212c49ecd). Using this code I am able to get User Identification Info which is enough for me to identify the user in API provider or create account for it.

This approach works for me. Hope it will work for you as well.

Note: this approach might be insecure.